# Installing python server for emacs-jedi

Tags: python, python-2.7, emacs, emacs-jedi

I am trying to install Jedi for emacs using marmalade package manager by following instructions here -- http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/latest/. The package manger installs Jedi along with its dependencies. But I cannot install python server using:

```
M-x jedi:install-server
```

because that command is not available even after restarting emacs after jedi installation. The only available commands are:

```
Possible completions are:
jedi:ac-setup   jedi:complete
jedi:dot-complete   jedi:get-in-function-call
jedi:goto-definition    jedi:goto-definition-next
jedi:goto-definition-pop-marker     jedi:setup
jedi:show-doc   jedi:show-jedi-version
jedi:start-dedicated-server     jedi:stop-server
jedi:toggle-debug-server
```

My .emacs has the following:

```lisp
(autoload 'jedi:setup "jedi" nil t)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)
```

I am using emacs on Mac OS X.

At this current state when I open any python file (I use python 2.7), I see the following appear automatically in the minibuffer:

```
deferred error : (error Server may raise an error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/t_nithyanandan/.emacs.d/elpa/jedi-0.1.2/jediepcserver.py", line 302, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/t_nithyanandan/.emacs.d/elpa/jedi-0.1.2/jediepcserver.py", line 298, in main
    jedi_epc_server(**vars(ns))
  File "/Users/t_nithyanandan/.emacs.d/elpa/jedi-0.1.2/jediepcserver.py", line 210, in jedi_epc_server
    import_jedi()
  File "/Users/t_nithyanandan/.emacs.d/elpa/jedi-0.1.2/jediepcserver.py", line 249, in import_jedi
    import jedi
ImportError: No module named jedi
)
```

I tried installing jedi using other methods such as el-get and also manually but those seem to not even go this far. I see that the jedi commands available are even lesser than listed above.

Could someone help point out what I am missing?

Thanks.

Edit: The primary purpose I would like to use Jedi is to use auto-completion features for python programming although I believe Jedi has many powerful features. For such a purpose, is the python server essential or could one work around it? Eventually, of course, I'd like to take advantage of many more features in Jedi.

Comment: I have posted my answer below that helped me solve this problem including other minor problems I faced along the way. @Chris, I couldn't upvote your answer because I don't have enough reputation points yet but thanks for pointing me in the right direction of fetching the right emacs-jedi version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem thanks to help from Chris and syohex from emacs-jedi github. Credit goes to them in tracing this to Jedi version.

I am just linking the discussion on [emacs-jedi issue #177](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi/issues/177) and pasting the workaround I found including other problems I encountered along the way.

I was using the Marmalade version which installs a much older version. So I uninstalled jedi and associated dependencies. I set my repository to MELPA and installed a much more recent version of jedi. This made the command

```
M-x jedi:install-server
```

available which wasn't the case earlier.

However, issuing that command gave an error

```
python-environment--make-with-runner: Program named "virtualenv" does not exist.
```

I made sure I added the location of virtualenv to PATH in my .bashrc.
So I looked up [emacs-jedi issue #158](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi/issues/158) which suggests installing exec-path-from-shell. I installed it from MELPA and added the lines

```
(when (memq window-system '(mac ns))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```

following instructions.

Restarting Emacs with the above lines gave an error:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: exec-path-from-shell-initialize
```

So I looked up Autoload issue #3 under exec-path-from-shell development (the link to this can be found in the link for emacs-jedi issue #177). Following one of the solutions, I restarted my computer, uninstalled and reinstalled exec-path-from-shell which magically did solve the problem that existed before the reboot.

Now I checked in emacs if virtualenv could be found using

```
M-! which virtualenv
```

It gave the right location.

Then I ran:

```
M-x jedi:install-server
```

which now seemed to run without trouble. The first time, there were messages about setting up a
default virtual environment under

```
/Users/XXX/.emacs.d/.python-environments
```

besides

```
Running: pip install --upgrade /Users/XXX/.emacs.d/elpa/jedi-20140321.1323/...Done
```

but in subsequent trials only the pip upgrade message was displayed.

Having seen that the server installed without trouble, I closed and restarted Emacs and opened a python script file. When I started editing, I got these messages in the minibuffers:

```
Error (jedi): Failed to start Jedi EPC server.
*** You may need to run "M-x jedi:install-server". ***
This could solve the problem especially if you haven't run the command yet
since Jedi.el installation or update and if the server complains about
Python module imports.
```

and

```
auto-complete error: (error Server may raise an error. Use "M-x epc:pop-to-last-server-process-buffer RET" to see full traceback:
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/Users/XXX/.emacs.d/elpa/jedi-0.1.2/jediepcserver.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`
)
```

Thus, I realized that I have to issue the command:

```
M-x jedi:install-server
```

every time I start Emacs before opening any python file. Then I was finally able to see the auto-completion features being available during editing.

Though I can run the above command every time manually, I wanted to automate it from my .emacs whenever Emacs is launched. It turned out that I had the following line in my .emacs

```
(setq jedi:server-command (list "python" "/Users/XXX/.emacs.d/elpa/jedi-0.1.2/jediepcserver.py"))
```

Upon removing this line in my .emacs, the problem went away and jedi is functional now.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem, however I did not have that line you removed. I fixed it by uninstalling jedi and epc using `pip uninstall jedi` and `pip uninstall epc`, and then installing them using `pip install --user epc` and `pip install --user jedi`.

Answer (score 1):

Marmalade currently [contains `jedi` version 0.1.2](http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/jedi), but you're looking at documentation for [version 0.2.0alpha2](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/latest/).

The [documentation for 0.1.2](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/released/) has [different instructions](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/released/#install):

> ### package.el (Marmalade or MELPA)
>
> You can install Jedi.el using package.el interface from [Marmalade](http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/jedi) or [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/). As package.el does not support installing non-elisp packages, you need to install Python part manually (see the next section).

And then in that next section, the imporant bit:

> Install [Jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi) and [python-epc](https://github.com/tkf/python-epc) by
>
> - `make requirements` (no need for root privileges) or
> - `pip install -r requirements.txt` if you want to determine where to install Python modules. You need root privileges (i.e., `sudo`) to install it in system directory.

You should be able to do `make requirements` from the `~/.emacs.d/elpa/jedi-0.1.2/` directory, but something like `pip install epc jedi` should work too.

Comment: I installed epc (0.0.5) and jedi (0.8.1-final0) using "sudo pip install epc jedi". I still get the same error. I am able to import jedi in ipython though.

Comment: @Nithya these modules must be installed into whatever Python environment you're using. So if, for instance, you're using a virtualenv, installing system wide probably won't help much. You may also need to use something like `pyvenv` in Emacs to make it use the proper virtualenv.

Comment: I have virtualenv installed but I wasn't using after activating any specific virtual environment. So I meant to install it system wide. I think I have managed to fix the issue with the main problem being I hadn't installed the latest version. I will post my answer here.