# ImportError in emacs jedi

Tags: python, emacs

I am trying to install emacs jedi. I am using Melpa to install it, in my init file I have

```
(require 'jedi)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
;; Standard Jedi.el setting                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)
```

I have access to all of the commands, but whenever I run them I get the error that says "You may need to run "M-x jedi:install-server" ", and then when run install server I get "ImportError: No module named jedi". I'm not sure where to go from here - I looked at the solution here [Installing python server for emacs-jedi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963476/installing-python-server-for-emacs-jedi) but that seems to be a different issue, and everywhere I've looked online I haven't seen a step by step solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a while ago, but it has gone unanswered so I thought I'd try help.

It seems Python cannot find jedi. Did you do 'pip install jedi'? This problem happened to me on Ubuntu 14.04, where somehow jedi was installed to the wrong location. My workaround was to install rope and then simply put jedi in the same directory, and then everything worked fine. If you cannot get jedi to work, rope is just as good.